# Loading a help file with PHP code to MySql Database?

Tags: php, mysql, load-data-infile

have a help file which i have created in Notepad++ 
with the following syntax

```
//Filename:PHP_Help.html

<!-- Heading of the Issue/Solution

// it may contain PHP Code or Mysql Queries or General Description
<?php

    // Code that fixed the issue/ Solution to a problem
?>

Some general Description
-->
```

I used the above format because in Notepad++ if i press 
"ALT + 0"

it display as

```
<!-- Heading of issue 1
<!-- Heading of issue 2
```

so that it helps in finding a solution to a problem reading the heading.
But the help file has increased in size and contains hundreds of issues

So i am trying to load the file to database and use PHP to search for the issues/solutions

My Database Schema would be like

```
Create table issues
(
 id int auto_increment primary key,
 header nvarchar(100),
 content text
);
```

My Question is how do i load the particular file to database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Read the file into a php variable:
$filecontents = file_get_contents ("PHP_Help.html");

// explode the string into individual records:
$records = explode ( "<!--" , $filecontents );

// work through the array of records:
foreach($records as $record) {
    // find your first linefeed
    $headingend = strpos($record, chr(13) );
    // get the heading
    $heading = substr($record, 0, $headingend);
    // and the content
    $content = substr($record, $headingend);
    // write to the database...
}
```